# How to extract a parent class from sub-classes that share very similar logic?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm trying to create a couple of custom buttons that I can eventually add to a JToolBar. I have one class that extends from JButton and looks like this:

```
public class CustomToolbarJButton extends JButton {
    public void setCustomProperties() {
        this.putClientProperty("Property1", "Value1");
    }

    // Some other CustomToolbarJButton specific code here.
}
```

I have another class, CustomToolbarJToggleButton that extends from JToggleButton and has the exact same code for the setCustomProperties() method.

My question is that, is there any way I can create an abstract parent class that these two classes can eventually inherit from, so that I can pull the setCustomProperties() method to that parent class.

### Edit

I wanted to add some context on what I eventually want to do.

I wanted to have a parent class like this:

```
public abstract class CustomToolbarButton extends <some-class> {
    public void setCustomProperties() {
        this.putClientProperty("Property1", "Value1");
    }
}

public class CustomToolbarJButton extends CustomToolbarButton {
    // Some other CustomToolbarJButton specific code here.
}

public class CustomToolbarJToggleButton extends CustomToolbarButton {
    // Some other CustomToolbarJToggleButton specific code here.
}
```

and eventually to add the buttons to the toolbar, I wanted to create a method like:

```
public void addCustomButtonToToolbar(boolean standardButtonOrToggleButton, String text) {
    CustomToolbarButton customToolbarButton = standardButtonOrToggleButton ? new CustomToolbarJButton(text) : new CustomToolbarJToggleButton(text);
    customToolbarButton.setCustomProperties();
    this.toolbar.add(customToolbarButton);  // toolbar is a JToolBar. I wanted to add the customToolbarButton directly to it, just like a standard JComponent.
}
```

Would something like this be possible?

Comment: Since java does not support multiple inheritance , i suggest you to go with an interface with  `setCustomProperties()`method on it or You have to have abstract class in-between your `CustomToolbarJButton`  class and `JButton`  class

Comment: If `CustomToolbarJButton` and `CustomToolbarJToggleButton` have the exact same properties, i.e. same names and same values, write a separate method that accepts an instance of either and sets the porperties. Perhaps a static method in a separate class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using `interface`, which are very similar to `abstract class` like this, but with only methods, and no fields:

```
public interface CustomProperties {
    public void setCustomProperties();
}
```

and:

```
public class CustomToolbarJButton extends JButton implements CustomProperties {
    public void setCustomProperties() {
        this.putClientProperty("Property1", "Value1");
    }

    // Some other CustomToolbarJButton specific code here.
}
```

notice the `implements` keyword, you can inherit from multiple interfaces at the same time..

as i think you may need that, you can create object of type CustomProperties with there subclasses.

```
CustomProperties obj = (CustomProperties) new CustomToolbarJButton();
```

i hope it helped :)

EDIT: this might help, probably you have different requirements..

```
public interface CustomProperties {
    public void setCustomProperties() {
        this.putClientProperty("Property1", "Value1");
    }
}
```

.

```
public class CustomToolbarJButton extends JButton implements CustomProperties {
    // Some other CustomToolbarJButton specific code here.
}
```

.

```
public class CustomToolbarJToggleButton extends JToggleButton implements CustomProperties {
    // Some other CustomToolbarJToggleButton specific code here.
}
```

and this: EDIT:

```
public void addCustomButtonToToolbar(boolean standardButtonOrToggleButton, String text) {
    CustomProperties customToolbarButton = standardButtonOrToggleButton ? new CustomToolbarJButton(text) : new CustomToolbarJToggleButton(text);
    customToolbarButton.setCustomProperties();
    this.toolbar.add((Component) customToolbarButton);
}
```

Comment: Notice: since Java 8 you can actually put default methods into interfaces that have a method body.

Comment: @AJo also look the comment above this :)

Comment: Thanks for the responses! If possible, can you please look at the edit that I made to the question giving some context on what I eventually wanted to achieve.

Comment: @AJo please look at this edit, i think this should work for you

Comment: @PranshuKhandal Thanks for your response. However, unfortunately since `CustomProperties` is not a `Component`, I cannot directly add it to the `JToolBar`. That's the exact point where I'm stuck.

Comment: @PranshuKhandal Even though `CustomToolbarJButton` and `CustomToolbarJToggleButton` are `Component`'s, their instances are being assigned to `CustomProperties` which is not a `Component` and therefore, the `add()` method of the `JToolBar` cannot be called directly on the `customToolbarButton` instance.

Comment: i have done type conversion, so this should help you, waiting for response

Comment: @PranshuKhandal Looks like this is the only way to go about it. Thanks for your prompt responses.